# When and how did Barbara Gordon (Batgirl) start walking again?

Tags: dc, batman, batgirl, barbara-gordon

After being shot and paralyzed by the Joker in *Batman: The Killing Joke*, Barbara Gordon (Batgirl), now being a paraplegic, becomes Oracle. After some indeterminate amount of time, she is able to walk again and revives her old superhero persona, Batgirl.

When and how did Barbara Gordon (Batgirl) start walking again, and how did she revive her old superhero persona, Batgirl?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Barbra Gordon was able to walk as of Batgirl #1 in the New 52.

It is later revealed in Batgirl #4 that she was a paraplegic for three years prior to surgery at a South African clinic.  This surgery took part a year prior to the events in Batgirl #1.

[image]

Batgirl #5 then revealed the nature of the surgery as neural implant surgery:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Nice job!

Answer (score 6):

When: AFAIK Barbra only started walking again after the [DC New 52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52)

How: Experimental surgery, extensive physical rehabilitation; and a universe "reboot".

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbara_Gordon#The_New_52%3a_Batgirl.2C_Birds_of_Prey_and_other_appearances_.282011.E2.80.93present.29):

> In the new, revised continuity, the events of The Killing Joke took place three years before the current storyline, and while it is established she was paraplegic during that time, Barbara Gordon is written as having regained her mobility after undergoing experimental surgery at a South African clinic

Answer (score -1):

I think Barbara Gordon starts to walk not during new 52 but not as pre flashpoint character but as a new 52 character since DC explains during convergence event she was still Oracle. However since Barbara was Batgirl and still in new 52 Barbara seems to remember where she was James Gordon's daughter or niece and where she has been attacked by the awful Joker who has paralyzed her. So in convergence she must be Oracle but she can walk again and does just that to not be recognized. Yeah i think despite évents Batgirl's past is still the same but with some exceptions when she was younger but it doesnt make much sense since Barbara Gordon was just 19 year old when she was Oracle. And in DC rebirth she still Batgirl but also Oracle sometime and also a librarian. To me her past is safe even in new 52.[image]

Comment: Since DC rebirth but even in new52 Barbara Gordon can walk again and still leads the Birds of prey since she did when Oracle. Unlike Robin or other Batgirls she still a Batgirl on her genre.